# Dragging multiple images on canvas in xaml window store app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I want to drag multiple images on canvas . I have one image in th canvas which has ManipulationDelta event to drag images

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    DragableItem.ManipulationDelta += DragableItem_ManipulationDelta;
    DragableItem.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
}


void DragableItem_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var translate = (TranslateTransform)DragableItem.RenderTransform;
     translateTransform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
                translateTransform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

its working fine but when I creating a runtime images on button click like this

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = new Image();
    string url = "ms-appx:///Assets/992829_484663934955807_859212711_n.jpg";
    BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();

    bm.UriSource = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
    image.Source = bm;
    image.Height = 100;
    image.Width = 100;

    image.Name = "img" + i++;
    image.ManipulationDelta+=Drag;
    DrawCanvas.Children.Add(image);

}
```

and a same event called drag like this

```
private void Drag(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var name = (Image)sender;
    name.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
    name.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
    var translate = (TranslateTransform)name.RenderTransform;

    translate.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    translate.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

}
```

Its not working for runtime images . I make a same event for every image control for dragging its not working , What is the mistake ,Need Help..

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it just not working? Is the Drag event being raised? Is the translate transform properly being set? I notice you don't show the TranslateTransform being added to your image when you create it in the code-behind. Is that an omission from your question or from your code?

Comment: drag event not firing

Comment: <Canvas x:Name="DrawCanvas" Width="500" Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image x:Name="DragableItem" Source="Assets/992829_484663934955807_859212711_n.jpg"  Width="100" Height="100" ></Image>

        </Canvas>  // for single image my xaml is this

Comment: Is IsManipulationEnabled set to true on those Images you're creating at runtime? The default is false.

Comment: no such property there what is the syntax

Comment: Ohhh, shoot, sorry, I just noticed you're doing windows store apps with xaml, not WPF. My bad. Let me start over thinking about it :)

Comment: Does it work if you set ManipulationMode when you create the object, rather than during the event?

Comment: yes its dragging but there is another problem now not moving from its position coming to to its original position

Comment: Update your question with the changes you've made to the code and the new result which you need help fixing.